# Deployment failed due to "Request had insufficient authentication scopes"

Tags: jenkins, google-cloud-storage, gcloud, google-managed-vm, google-cloud-sdk

I created new VM instance (jenkins-server) on project1 and I installed jenkins server on it . one of the jenkins jobs should build my app and deploy it on project2 with the following command

```
mvn gcloud:deploy -Dgcloud.gcloud_project=project2 -Dgcloud.version=jenkins-build-1
```

The command fails due to the following error :

```
[INFO] Beginning deployment...
[INFO] DEBUG: No bucket specified, retrieving default bucket.
[INFO] DEBUG: {u'status': u'PERMISSION_DENIED', u'message': u'Request had insufficient authentication scopes.', 
u'code': 403}
[INFO] ERROR: Error Response: [403] Request had insufficient authentication scopes.
[INFO] DEBUG: Using bucket [].
[INFO] DEBUG: (gcloud.preview.app.deploy) Could not retrieve the default Google Cloud Storage bucket for [project2]. Please try again or use the [bucket] argument.
```

I created new bucket on project2 called jenkins-server and tried the command again with the bucket argument

```
[INFO] Beginning deployment...
[INFO] DEBUG: Using bucket [gs://jenkins-server].
[INFO] DEBUG: Host: appengine.google.com
[INFO] DEBUG: (gcloud.preview.app.deploy) Required scopes ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/appengine.admin', 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform'] missing from [list of scopes]. This VM instance probably needs to be recreated with the missing scopes
```

Project1 is created with full permissions

Google SDK version is up to date : Google Cloud SDK 95.0.0

**[EDIT][UPDATE]**

on project1 I used an image with pre-installed jenkins on jenkins-server instance but I recreated the instance with ubuntu 14.04 LTS only and installed everything else manually (cloud sdk , tomcat server,jenkins ,maven ...)

The issue above disappeared but now I am getting different error

```
 ERROR: (gcloud.preview.app.deploy) Could not synchronize files. The gsutil command exited with status [1]
```

and after checking the log file I can see the following error :

```
Building synchronization state... Caught non-retryable exception while listing file:///tmp/tmpsgDQKG: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/tmp/tmpsgDQKG/cc79fffba16616623f47691da45b33db1beb4209.pem'
 CommandException: Caught non-retryable exception - aborting rsync
```

this is the same error  for default and custom bucket

Appreciate your help

Comment: For the second error, what context is gsutil being executed under?  Is the file listed in the exception a valid file?

Comment: @TravisHobrla It is being executed under mvn gcloud:deploy command , here is the output :


    [INFO] Building synchronization state...
    [INFO] Caught non-retryable exception while listing file:///tmp/tmpofq2NO: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/tmp/tmpofq2NO/babfa40c84b6077baf7352fbefd86de948e26b3c.pem'
    [INFO] CommandException: Caught non-retryable exception - aborting rsync

    [INFO] DEBUG: Running command: [/bin/bash /home/tareq/google-cloud-sdk/bin/gsutil -m rsync -R -c /tmp/tmpofq2NO gs://staging.tradeos-test1.appspot.com/], Env: [None]

Comment: @TravisHobrla please note that this file doesn't exist under /tmp

Comment: @TravisHobrla please see the full lod here: [link] https://code.google.com/p/google-cloud-sdk/issues/detail?can=2&start=0&num=100&q=&colspec=ID%20Type%20Status%20Priority%20Milestone%20Owner%20Summary&groupby=&sort=&id=532

Comment: Thanks - I think the issue you filed is a good description.

Answer (score 1):

As per the detail for [issue 532](https://code.google.com/p/google-cloud-sdk/issues/detail?id=532) which was filed, the workaround was to deploy using `gcloud config set app/use_gsutil false`, however this is now the default as of gcloud version 106.0.0